# Caml query - View date type column without time stamp

Tags: mysql, sharepoint, caml

Sharepoint caml query code i've used given below -

```
<Where>
      <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name='ID' /> 
         <Value Type='Counter'>248</Value>
      </Eq>
   </Where>
   <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name='eStartdate' />
      <FieldRef Name='eEndDate' />
   </ViewFields>
```

while viewing i am getting time stamp along with date.I need only date part.

Result -
[Click here for query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVvmB.png)

I am getting Timestamp while querying. Can anyone help me with query to view date columns without timestamp.
Expected result as per example - estartdate - 28-08-2020 , eEndDate - 28-08-2020

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint date-time field always contains date and time, the time portion is just set to a default value and hidden from UI if the field is set to date only. hence I think it's not possible to only display date part as CAML schema does not have this attribute. I suggest you use custom code to format the date.

BR